# Error while exporting GridPanel (EXT) to Excel

Tags: extjs, export-to-excel, gridpanel

given the function to export the Gridpanel

```
    Dim json As String = e.ExtraParams("GridRows")
    Dim eSubmit As New StoreSubmitDataEventArgs(json, Nothing)
    Dim xml As XmlNode = eSubmit.Xml

    Me.Response.Clear()
    Me.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Me.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=submittedData.xlsx")

    Dim xtExcel As New XslCompiledTransform()

    xtExcel.Load(Server.MapPath("Excel.xslt"))
    xtExcel.Transform(xml, Nothing, Me.Response.OutputStream)
    Me.Response.[End]()
```

the export isn't working , but i can see all the content in a window error while executing the project , status code 200 the message is "BADRESPONSE: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null" why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2):

Add `IsUpload="True"` to your DirectEvent